# Proving nicely that $3+\omega=\omega$ where $\omega$ is the smallest limit ordinal.

Tags: ordinals

I just learned about ordinal numbers and I am a bit confused to show things with them. Let $\omega$ be the smallest limit ordinal. 
I want to show that $3+\omega=\omega$. So the definition I have of $3+\omega$ (since $\omega$ is a limit ordinal) is :
$3+\omega = sup\{n+3:n<\omega \}$. Then the definition of the sup I have is $supX=\{\gamma : \exists x \in X \text{such that } \gamma \in x\}$, so we have :
$3+\omega = \{\gamma : \exists x \in \{n+3:n<\omega \}\ \text{such that } \gamma \in x\}$. But how to show this is equal to $\omega$?

Comment: Incidentally, "limit ordinal" is often defined to include $\emptyset$, making $\omega$ the second smallest.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n < \omega$, $3+n < \omega$, so $3+\omega \leq \omega$. On the other hand, for any $n < \omega$, $3+\omega \geq 3+n > n$. Thus $3+\omega \geq \omega$.

Comment: Tank you for the explanation. Some questions that might sound stupid :  
If $n < \omega$ what argument can we use to say that $3+n < \omega$? also you say that $n<\omega$ implies $n<\omega$ and thus $3+\omega \leq \omega$. So I guess the first statement should be $n\leq \omega$ implies $n \leq\omega$. This all may seem obvious to you but a lot of things that seemed obvious to me for normal numbers are not true anymore for ordinals.

Comment: @roi_saumon: I listed a lot of basic ordinal arithmetic results in [this 29 October 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5324067), such as: "[$+$ is] *associative, not commutative, continuous in the right variable, not continuous in the left variable* $(\sup\{n+\omega: n< \omega \}= \omega< \omega \cdot 2 = \sup\{n: n < \omega \} + \omega ),$ *strictly increasing in the right variable, non-decreasing in the left variable (not strict:* $1 + \omega = 2 + \omega).$" The proofs of these will depend on how your book/notes define ordinal addition, multiplication, etc.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I see. I am following notes that don't have proofs for this. Any good book with these proofs that you recommend?

Comment: @roi_saumon: Maybe [**Basic Set Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821827316) by Shen/Vereshchagin, which doesn't have lengthy treatments of axiomatics and other issues that are rather tangential to someone only interested in ordinal arithmetic. Possibly the most detailed treatment of ordinal arithmetic I know of in a beginning set theory text is [**Introduction to Set Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0898740061) by James Donald Monk (1969), if you can find it in a library. And of course there is [the bible](https://www.worldcat.org/title/cardinal-and-ordinal-numbers/oclc/796464).